# How do I display child post types in the parent post type template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, children

I have a custom post type called `airports` which uses a template called `single-airports.php`.

I have created a new airport called *Gatwick* and created a child of this called called *Gatwick North Terminal*.

How do I get the permalink of Gatwick's children to display on the Gatwick page (`single-airports.php`).

I would greatly appreciate any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found the answer!

Hopefully this helps some other people!

### EDIT

**Improved Answer!**

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'airports', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <button><?php _e('View', 'text_domain'); ?></button>
</a>

<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is totally wrong. One should never ever use `query_posts()`

Comment: Darn. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I've amended my answer! Is that any better?

Comment: Much better. I have removed the other wrong section of code. Just a note, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` (*I have fixed that*). `wp_reset_query()` is used with `query_posts()` ;-) You should read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/31545)